# counting the number of occurrences of the letter in a string

Tags: string, assembly, sparc

I am trying to count the number of occurrences of the letter in a string within a SPARC machine.But I cannot seem to find the way to code this problem. How can I get started? 
Here is an example:

```
   Enter a string: stackoverflow

   The letter o appears 2 times
```

Comment: The best way to get started is to write some pseudo code and then turn that into assembly. Another great suggestion is to actually show up for class. :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130255963) book will help you. Also you can write this program in C and watch the assembly generated by compiler. Something like `gcc t.c -S`. Also there are the [Sparc v9 manual](https://cr.yp.to/2005-590/sparcv9.pdf). And another helpful thing - [SPARC Assembly Language Reference Manual](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0ahUKEwjTy9zl54LOAhXKKiwKHfNnAjIQFggzMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cse.scu.edu%2F~atkinson%2Fteaching%2Fsp05%2F259%2Fsparc.pdf&usg=AFQjCNF-kaD0LqArHwGQXmHk2tHnHsqw2Q&sig2=WYuoeVgLfRpxCKZOI370iw&bvm=bv.127521224,d.bGg&cad=rjt).